# What voltage difference should I use for 10BASE-T?

Tags: voltage, ethernet, differential

Looking through some resources about the electronics behind ethernet, specifically the 10BASE-T standard, I've found some conflicting information about what the voltage differential should be for the signals sent.

The [Wikipedia page for Ethernet over twisted wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair#Cabling) states that

> A 10BASE-T transmitter sends two differential voltages, +2.5 V or −2.5 V.

This claim does cite a source, however I cannot access it.

In contrast, the the 802.3-1985 IEEE-standard states:

> [the maximum voltage difference], shall be < 1315mV

> [W]hen the A lead is 160mV positive with respect to the B lead, the interface circuit is in the HI state, and when the A lead is 160mV negative with respect to the B lead, the interface circuit is in the LO state.

<sup>(*7.4.1.1 Differential Output Voltage, Loaded* and *7.4.2.1 Receiver  Threshold  Levels*)</sup>

If I'm interpreting this correctly, it's saying that the differential voltage can be anywhere between 160mV and 1315mV, which ±2.5 is not.

As a third source, I found [this video by Ben Eater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8CmibhvZ0c), wherein he probes a live 10BASE-T Ethernet wire. In it, we can read the oscilloscope:

[image: Oscilloscope screenshot]

Here, we can conclude that the voltage over this specific connection is ±1V, which agrees with my interpretation of the standard.

Thus my question is, is my interpretation of the standard correct, and is Wikipedia wrong here?

I can think of some things which might resolve this conflict, although I can not find any references for any of them:

- The standard has been updated since 1985, allowing ±2.5V
- Perhaps Wikipedia and the standard are referring to different ways of measuring the voltage differential (peek to peek vs amplitude). As 2.5V / 2 ≈ 1315mV, this seems not too implausible.
- As the 802.3-1985 standard does claim you don't *have* to follow it, perhaps Wikipedia is referring to some other standard for 10BASE-T :/

Comment: 10BaseT is 5Vpp differential. I recall it is was very hard to design around that standard, since supply voltages had dropped way below half of that. Maybe someone used a lower supply and kept the 10BaseT for legacy, but lower supply, or standards were modified. *check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202554/how-is-a-twisted-pairs-2-5v-used-to-send-a-1-or-a-0 (TBase-Te Mau)

Answer (score 1):

Microchip says do the  IEEE 802.3 compliance testing with these limits with loopback mode on their PHY's for 10 Base-T:

> Pass specification is based on the following:
> Vmin: -2.8V to -2.2V
> Vmax: +2.2V to +2.8V

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/AN2686-Ethernet-Compliance-Test-10BASET-100BASETX-1000BASET.pdf

They don't say exactly *which* testing standard they are getting these numbers from, they only say IEEE 802.3, but I'd trust them. I'd say 1V is probably not right. The real way to go about this would to [buy the standard](https://standards.ieee.org/) and read it.

Comment: IEEE 802.3 standards are available for free for everyone through the "IEEE Get" program - just Google it